# remove special characters from text

Tags: javascript, regex, escript

I am trying to remove special characters from a given text.

I've tried to replace it with:

```
var stringToReplace = 'ab風cd  � abc 123 € AAA';
var newText = stringToReplace.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
```

but it's not working.
I want that the newText will be:

```
newText = 'ab cd      abc 123   AAA'
```

I've tried some regex but none of them seem to work.
the real problem is with '風' (those kind of characters).
any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use.

```
stringToReplace.replace(/\W/g, ' ');
```

Output

`"ab cd      abc 123   AAA"`

Comment: thanks, it works! but what if I want Hebrew letters to stay in the text, for example: 'ab風cd  � abc 123 € AAA שלום'  expected text: 'ab cd      abc 123   AAA שלום'

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below,

```
> 'ab風cd  � abc 123 € AAA'.replace(/[^\dA-Za-z]/g, " ")
'ab cd      abc 123   AAA'
```

`[^\dA-Za-z]` negated character class which matches any character but not of digits or alphabets.

**OR**

```
> 'ab風cd  � abc 123 € AAA'.replace(/[^\dA-Za-z\s]/g, "")
'abcd   abc 123  AAA'
> 'ab風cd  � abc 123 € AAA'.replace(/[^\dA-Za-z\s]/g, " ")
'ab cd      abc 123   AAA'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bad regex there, it should be:

```
var newText = stringToReplace.replace(/[^\da-z]/ig, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `/\W/g` as your regex

`\W - The opposite of \w. Matches any non-alphanumeric character.`

For example:

```
var string = 'ab風cd  � abc 123 € AAA';
string = string.replace(/\W/g, ' ')
alert(string); // ab cd      abc 123   AAA
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vgwv6ht2/